# Is there a way to use two @* in an xpath selector to select an element?

Tags: xpath

I have an HTML element I would like to select that looks like this:

```html
<button data-button-id="close" class="modal__cross modal__cross-web"></button>
```

Now clearly I can use this XPath selector:

```
//button[(contains(@data-button-id,'close')) and (contains(@class,'modal'))]
```

to select the element.  However, I would really like to select buttons that have both `close` and `modal` contained in *any* attributes. So I can generalize the selector and say:

```
//button[(contains(@*,'close')) and (contains(@class,'modal'))]
```

and that works.  What I'd love to do is extend it to this:

```
//button[(contains(@*,'close')) and (contains(@*,'modal'))]
```

but that doesn't return any results. So clearly that doesn't mean what I'd like it to mean.  Is there a way to do it correctly?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to select required element:

```
//button[@*[contains(., 'close')] and @*[contains(., 'modal')]]
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using XPath 1.0: in 1.0, if you supply a node-set as the first argument to contains(), it takes the first node in the node-set. The order of attributes is completely unpredictable, so there's no way of knowing whether `contains(@*, 'close')` will succeed or not. In 2.0+, this gives you an error.

In both 1.0 and 2.0, `@*[contains(., 'close')]` returns true if any attribute contains "close" as a substring.

Answer (score 1):

This expression works:
 `//button[attribute::*[contains(.,"close")] and attribute::*[contains(.,"modal")]]`

Given this html

```
<button data-button-id="close" class="modal__cross modal__cross-web"></button>
<button key="close" last="xyz_modal"></button>
```

Testing with xmllint

```
echo -e 'cat //button[attribute::*[contains(.,"close")] and attribute::*[contains(.,"modal")]]\nbye' | xmllint --html --shell test.html 
/ > cat //button[attribute::*[contains(.,"close")] and attribute::*[contains(.,"modal")]]
 -------
<button data-button-id="close" class="modal__cross modal__cross-web"></button>
 -------
<button key="close" last="xyz_modal"></button>
/ > bye
```

Comment: It appears that attribute::* is just a long form for @*, so you're really suggesting the same thing as @jaSON's solution.  So I guess you're both right essentially.

Comment: @LMC Yes, my answer appeared 3 minutes later. But actually your initial solution was wrong and you made an edit only after my answer was published

Comment: Yes, chronologically LMC made an incorrect answer, JaSON made a correct answer, and LMC edited (maybe an hour later) to have a correct solution equivalent to JaSON.  That's why I accepted JaSON.